# Real Time Editor

Tags: javascript, php, html, domcontentloaded

I am trying to get it where when the Page loads, it will automatically load the Code that I have in the Text Box, I was thinking maybe using a Dom Content Loaded? Any Suggestions?

```
<!--- Shows the Code that Is inserted into the Text Box -->             

 <div  id="DisplayCode"></div>

<!--- End Of Shows the Code that Is inserted into the Text Box --> 





<!-- Text Box Code Where You input the Code --> 
        <div class="form1">
        <textarea id="Code" value="insert Code Here" rows="14" cols="183" ><!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>

        <h1> Insert Your Code Here </h1> 

        </body>
        </html>
           </textarea>  

    <!-- End of Text Box Where You Enter your Code -->





    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Code').keyup(function(){
            $('#DisplayCode').html($(this).val());
        });
    });
    </script>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#DisplayCode').html($("#Code").val());
    $('#Code').keyup(function(){
        $('#DisplayCode').html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Simply do that on domready?